# Golang math/big Unmarshal Lost Precision

Tags: go, bigdecimal, unmarshalling

I have a struct like:

```
type Msg struct {
    F1  *big.Float `json:"F1,string"`
}
```

Then I got a message in `json` from a message queue and then I want to unmarshal that json message into my `Msg` struct:

```
// jsonMsg = {"F1": "1000314.451234"}
var msg Msg
json.Unmarshal(jsonMsg, &msg)
```

But I got:

```
fmt.Println("go object:",msg.F1.String()) // 1000314.45, precision lost
```

So the precision is lost when my string `"1000314.451234"` is unmarshaled to a `Msg` object in golang. I wonder if this is bug? How can I get the full precision? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The precision is not lost when you unmarshall. It's "lost" when you convert the Float to String to print it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "math/big"
)

type Msg struct {
    F1  *big.Float `json:"F1,string"`
}

func main() {
    jsonMsg := []byte(`{"F1": "1000314.451234"}`)
    var msg Msg
    json.Unmarshal(jsonMsg, &msg)
    fmt.Println("go object:",msg.F1.String())
    fmt.Printf("go object: %f", msg.F1)
}
```

The output of this test will be :

```
go object: 1000314.451
go object: 1000314.451234
```

So just depend how you print the data.
Godoc [fmt printing](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing)

Comment: Yes. It is because by default, string function uses  msg.Text('g', 10) So it look like that precision has been lost. When "fmt.Println("go object:", msg.F1.Text('f', 6))", you can see that there's no lost.
I too was about to post same thing but you beat me to it.